# Get address shipping selected paypal android SDK

Tags: android, paypal

I've an app android with `paypal SDK 2.0` and I do the payments perfect but I don't be able to get the address shipping selected in the payment, I get the payment `JSONObject` with the id, create time..etc but I don't know how to get the address selected details...

Answer (score 0):

When you do the [verify payment step](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) from your server, the selected shipping address should come back with the payment details.